# Pyspark MultiProcessing Approach Or Code Optimizarion

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Could you please help me on the below case in the databricks pyspark 2.4.3 code, which processes terabytes of json data read from aws s3 bucket.

case 1:

Currently, I'm reading multiple tables sequentially to get the day count
from each table.

For ex: table_list.csv has one column with multiple table names

year = 2019 
month = 12

```
tablesDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header",false).load("s3a://bucket//source/table_list.csv")
tabList = tablesDF.toPandas().values.tolist()
for table in tabList:
    tab_name = table[0]
```

// Snowflake Settings and snowflake  table count()

```
sfOptions = dict(
  "sfURL" -> "",
  "sfAccount" -> "",
  "sfUser" -> "",
  "sfPassword" -> "",
  "sfDatabase" -> "",
  "sfSchema" -> "",
  "sfWarehouse" -> "",
)

// Read data as dataframe

sfxdf = spark.read
  .format("snowflake")
  .options(**sfOptions)
  .option("query", "select y as year,m as month,count(*) as sCount from
{} where y={} and m={} group by year,month").format(tab_name,year,month)
      .load()
```

//databricks delta lake

```
     dbxDF = spark.sql("select y as year,m as month,count(*) as dCount from
db.{} where y={} and m={}" group by year,month).format(tab_name,year,month)

resultDF = dbxDF.join(sfxdf, on=['year', 'month'], how='left_outer'
).na.fill(0).withColumn("flag_col", expr("dCount == sCount"))


    finalDF = resultDF.withColumn("table_name",
lit(tab_name)).select("table_name","year","month","dCount","sCount","flag_col")


    finalDF.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').option('header', 'true').save("s3a://outputs/reportcsv)
```

Questions:

1) Currently, I'm doing sequence based running using count query, by taking etables by one one.

2) How to read all the tables from the csv file in parallel and run the count query in parallel and distribute the jobs across the cluster?

3) Could you please show me how to optimise the above code in the pyspark for multi thread processing of all the count query at the same time?

Thanks
Anbu